# Number of tables in BigQuery query limitation

Tags: google-bigquery

In the Quota Policy, there is a **Maximum query length: 10KB** and one of the query features is the possibility to use multiple tables with the same schema, if I don't exceed the 10kb, is there a limit number of tables in the query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query up to 1,000 tables in a single query: just combine them with commas
as in `SELECT foo FROM datast.table1, dataset.table2...`

Comment: Perfect, today our analytics tool who runs on top of BigQuery creates queries with date range, so to optimize the processed data, I'm thinking to create partitions (splited tables) by day, this is the best solution?

Comment: Yes, this is a good way to partition your data. It may also help keep costs down, since your queries will only be scanning the tables you include in the queries.

Comment: Actually there is a limit. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is currently wrong (Oct 2014). There **is** a limit on the number of tables that can be referenced in a query: 1000.

That applies to table ranges as well. Take a look at [Querying Data Limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#limits) on official BigQuery documentation.

(By the way, the current maximum query length is also different: 256 KB)

Sharding tables can reduce your cost, but can increase the query time. According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#from), "up to 50ms per additional table".

Of course these limits can change over time, so make sure to take a look at the official documentation instead of SO about current limits and quotas.